# Using custom vocabulary n-grams for sklearn CountVectorizer

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I want to have a custom `CountVectorizer` vocabulary to note the presence or absence of an expression. Rather than words, I want it to detect combinations of words.

Based on my custom vocabulary, I would like `sklearn` to detect "big dog".

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

cvec = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=['big dog', 'cat'])

cvec.fit_transform(['The big dog and the cat']).toarray()
```

```
array([[0, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

It doesn't seem to detect "big dog" which is the combination of words I'm looking for. Is there a way to do this, or can this function only detect words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define ngram_range bigger than `(1, 1)`, for example `(1, 2)` if you want `sklearn` to consider combinations of 2 words.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

cvec = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=['big dog', 'cat'], ngram_range=(1, 2))

cvec.fit_transform(['The big dog and the cat']).toarray()
```

```
array([[1, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: As you can tell by the output, "big dog" isn't detected, as there is a 0 at index 0

Comment: Oh, it works if I use the argument `ngram_range=(1, 2)` if you want to add that to your answer I'll accept it